# During the ordering phase, mutiple transactions are batched together. How does the ordering and batching happen?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

i had a query regarding the ordering service of Hyperledger fabric. If the transactions are linked to one another and it takes time for one transaction to get completed. For example, a delivery system on blockchain. 
If the order delivered block takes time to be added. How does the ordering service order the remaining nodes?

Comment: orderer does not orders nodes but it orders transaction using a pluggable trust engine (CFT or BFT) and broadcasts them to the network of peers who validate and add them in their ledger(copies) maintaining the consistent ledger state across the network

Answer (score 0):

In general, the output of a transaction has to make it into a block and be marked valid on commit before it is available to another transaction to use.